# What size bulb replaces these in a Harbor Beeze ceiling fan?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

My house has several Harbor Breeze ceiling fans.  Two bulbs have burned out but I can't seem to find what size bulbs should replace them.  Here's a picture of one of the burned bulbs (right) and a generic ceiling fan bulb with an intermediate A15 base (left).

[image: some bulbs]

I've searched around Home Depot and Amazon but haven't found what size this is.  There's also no model number on the outside of the fan that I can find to look up the manual.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a description or number on the base of the original bulb? Also can you post a photo of the fan?

Answer (score 1):

A refers to the shape of the glass part. 15 is the diameter of the base.  So A stands for arbitrary, E stands for edison, T stands for tubular and so on. The confusion is usually the base measurements. Typical bulbs are E, size of base. The small base size is known as an E12 Candelabra base.

Anything with that size, screw-in base should fit in the socket, but it has to be A15 to fit within the shade.

Also, watch out for the rating or brightness of the bulb. The Harbor Breeze model ceiling fans usually say MAX 60W. So that's around 14W for CFL type bulbs and 6W LED - which will cost the most, but are the cheapest to run in the long term.

Comment: No, that MAX wattage is actual bulb power -- you can put a 60W LED bulb into the fan, but you'd go blind if you did ;)

Comment: It's often pretty hard to find the actual power draw of LED bulbs for some reason. But from what I've seen even 100w LED replacements only draw about 21watts.

Comment: @HMSCelestia every LED bulb package I have ever seen proudly proclaims it's actual energy usage along side it's incandescent equivelent output.  That is basically the whole selling point of them.

Comment: Wow, the ones I've seen only show the projected savings. It's been a bit since I've bought some though.

Answer (score 1):

I have 6 of the 52" Harbor Breeze fan/lights.

I believe you are looking for a "G" shaped bulb, with a base of "16.5" not to exceed 60 watts.

A 60 watt incandescent bulb is equivalent to (8 to 9) watt LED bulb.  If you chose to go with a LED replacement.

So the packaging must say "G16.5" 120v and whatever wattage you would like, just as long as you do not exceed 60 watts incandescent or 9 watt LED.

Halogen bulbs put out a lot of heat, may even melt fixture, I would NOT use a Halogen bulb.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No 60w is the maximum wattage if you could find a 60w led or cfl with that much power consumption you could use it but as 3 phase said you would be blinded by the amount of light.

Answer (score 0):

They use the e-11 mini candelabra base bulb.
 This is smaller than the 'standard' e-12 that is found in night lights and some chandeliers.
E-11 = 11mm diameter, e-12 = 12mm diameter.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
I had a hard time figuring out which bulb to use on the Harbor Breeze fixture that the prior owners installed. Current bulb labeling doesn't use "E" numbers. This 100W/120 volt mini candelabra base halogen light worked and is dimmable.

Comment: This is a 100w lamp it is not compatible with your fixture, most harbor breeze fans have current limiters and putting a lamp that is almost double the listed wattage will reduce the life of the current limiter, if an older fan prior to the government requirement for limiters it may melt the fixture parts, possibly cause a fire in the wires.

Comment: This. This is why the fire-prevention people made fan builders install limiter circuits.